Transactions per time range in Grafana/Prometheus using NGINX metrics
I'm still new to Grafana and I'm trying to extract hourly traffic data using the nginxplus_location_zone_responses metric. Just want to know if I'm using the correct promQL query.
Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!
I'm currently using this query:

sum by(location_zone) (increase(nginxplus_location_zone_responses{code=~"2xx|4xx|5xx"}[1H]))

